# Owner of the file not being displayed properly in LINUX Terminal

Tags: linux, files, terminal, ownership

I want the terminal to display the user name that created a particular file, so when I traverse all the way to that file and type in the command `ls -l filename.docx` or even `ls -la /path/to/file`, it shows the output as:

```
staff 1344 May 18 11:03 (filename).docx.
```

So I don't understand why does it display

```
'staff 1344'
```

instead of using my actual user name.

How am I supposed to obtain the actual username in this case (provided I logged in from my admin account)?

Comment: Can you↑ please clarify what you need to happen and what your looking for

Comment: You may want to add the complete output of your `ls` commands. As for now it does not look like and some information might be missing or could be misunderstood.

Comment: I wonder if your username (or maybe groupname) somehow got a CR added to it -- try piping `ls -l file_or_glob | cat -v` and see if that's any better.

Comment: You output is incomplete. It way be because there is a carriage return character in the user-name. Please add output of `who am i`.

Answer (score 2):

Your output fragment is incomplete.

In your line

```
staff 1344 May 18 11:03 (filename).docx
```

the `staff` is the group of the file and `1344` is the size.

A complete line should look similar to this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  staff 1344 May 18 11:03 (filename).docx
```

Here `user` is the user name, `staff` is the group name and `1344` is the size.

Comment: So recently me and my friend set up a local network between our laptops and gave each other full read/write access rights, now I guess it's displaying the owner's username when I type in that command but here's another problem: my friend created a file on that shared network and when I type in that command for the file he created, it still shows my username instead of his. Any clue why that might be the case?

Comment: @ddd You have the same UID. Your UID is something like 1000 on your machine, and he has that same UID on his machine.  When he looks at the file, he will see his username, even on files that you create.

Comment: @Kusalananda So would that always be the case? We were actually trying to understand the security mechanism underneath a shared network. Would there be a case when his and my UID are different on a shared network?

Comment: @Kusalananda Also how can our laptops have the same UID when are devices are separate machines on a common network?

Comment: @ddd+ UID _User_ ID (and also GID Group ID) is just a number and by default is assigned separately on each system, although systems set up for common admin (like in schools or businesses) sometimes have them coordinated. You may be confusing with GUID Globally _Unique_ ID aka UUID Universally _Unique_ ID which are computed in a way that makes them unique, or tries to.

Comment: @ddd If your question about the UID/GID is not yet answered, you should port it as a new question, not as comments here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question really well but if you need to see the owner of the file you can:

```
$stat -c "%U" filename.docx
```

Here you can see the information that the `stat` command gives:

```
$stat .ssh/known_hosts
```

Output:

```
  File: .ssh/known_hosts
  Size: 886             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe05h/65029d    Inode: 527954      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/kristjan)   Gid: ( 1000/kristjan)
Access: 2019-05-18 07:06:48.455714935 +0000
Modify: 2019-05-18 07:06:48.359714937 +0000
Change: 2019-05-18 07:06:48.359714937 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: When I type that it displays- 'stat: illegal option -- c'

Comment: @ddd what is the exact command your trying

Comment: The command I originally used is 'ls -l filename.docx'. I'll be more specific here, me and my friend we set up a shared p2p network between our laptops and my friend created a file in a shared folder of ours but when I type in that command it displays my username as the owner of the file instead of his. I tried your mentioned command as well but then it just displayed 'stat: illegal option -- c'

Comment: @ddd Sorry but you are very hard to understand and what the problem is, I tried, good luck!